# Matplotlib Coherence plot ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm Attempting to plot a coherence plot similar to the [Matplotlib Gallery](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/cohere_demo.html) from an imported csv using this code:

```
r1 = mru['r1']
r2 = mru['r2']
t = mru['time']

plt.cohere(t, r1, 'b-', t, r2, 'g-', ax=ax10)
ax10.xlim(0,5)
ax10.xlabel('time')
ax10.ylabel('r1 and r2')
ax10.grid(True)
```

I get this Error:

```
ValueError: Coherence is calculated by averaging over *NFFT*
length segments.  Your signal is too short for your choice of *NFFT*
```

So I changed the value to two:

```
plt.cohere(t, r1, 'b-', t, r2, 'g-', NFFT=2, ax=ax10)
```

And get this Error:

```
TypeError: cohere() got multiple values for keyword argument 'NFFT'
```

How can I properly plot the correlation?

Comment: How long is your original signal? Calculating coherence based on a DFT based on a selection of 2-point windows is meaningless. NFFT normally defaults to 256, so your signal must be quite short.

Comment: Its a comparison of two hours worth of roll data of two different VRU's..I thought it would be ample. I entered 2 as a check.

Comment: Ok - also, you're misusing the function. I'll answer in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments you're passing to `cohere()` are wrong. You don't need the time, you simply need the two series `r1` and `r2`, together with the common sampling rate `Fs`.

You're getting the original error message because the function expects NFFT to be the 3rd argument, as per the documentation (http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.cohere), and it's somehow interpreting `'b-'` as a number. When you explicitly define NFFT elsewhere, you're then doubling up on the definition of NFFT.

Try

`plt.cohere(r1, r2, NFFT=256)`

Or whatever value of NFFT you need. Make sure you get your sampling rate correct too, otherwise your results will not be physically meaningful.

Comment: I still get `ValueError: Coherence is calculated by averaging over *NFFT*
length segments.  Your signal is too short for your choice of *NFFT*.` my sample rate is 1s

Comment: What is the sampling rate of your data? And how many samples are in your series? Edit - just saw your sampling rate. I take it you mean 1 Hz.

Comment: count = 1959.000000 @ 1Hz

Comment: Can you please post a sample of what `mru['r1']` looks like?

Comment: `0.21,0.21,0.04,0.02,0.03,-0.08` Its roll in degrees

Comment: OK, with NFFT=1024, you will only have one complete window. Try NFFT=256.